# domain of thr function of logarithm and quadratic

Tags: functional-analysis

[image]

In this question why option c is not the answer .

Can anybody please explain me that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answers (1) and (3) are actually identical, because the constraints on $a,b,c$ imply $a,b,c>0$, i.e. $-b/2a < 0$.